# XSLT value-of won't load data

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, xslt, serialization

I'm building asp.net mvc 5 web application, and i have come to a process where i need to do some serialization.

I have a form with a post method and i need to save the data from that form into a PDF file, and in order to do that, i'm saving these data in an XML file then i convert that file to HTML using XSLT and from that to PDF finally.

Now everything is working properly, but when i open the PDF file to see if the data is stored, i see nothing, just the structure i made with XSLT file.

I believe i did something wrong with the XSLT file and here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">


<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>Adherent</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>numero adhesion</th>
            <th>nom</th>
            <th>numero adhesion</th>
            <th>nom</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="NumeroAdhesion"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Nom"/>
            </td>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the code that generated both XML and PDF :

```
    public static void SaveDataToFile(Adherent adherent)
    {

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Adherent));
        var path = @"C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\Affiliation\BulletinAdhesion\eSign\XML\" + adherent.NumeroAdhesion + ".xml";
        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, adherent);

        file.Close();
        CreatePDF(adherent.NumeroAdhesion);
    }
    public static void CreatePDF(string filename)
    {


        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\Affiliation\BulletinAdhesion\eSign\XSLT\XSLTFile1.xslt"))
        {
            transform.Load(reader);
        }
        StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\Affiliation\BulletinAdhesion\eSign\XML\"+ filename +".xml"))
        {
            transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
        }
        IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
        Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(results.ToString()).SaveAs(@"C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\Affiliation\BulletinAdhesion\eSign\PDF\" + filename + ".pdf");

    }
```

**Update :** 
Here is the XML File

[image]

**Update :** 
Here is the XML file as a code sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Adherent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<AdherentId>0</AdherentId>
<NumeroAdhesion>AD000001</NumeroAdhesion>
<NumeroPolice>AD000001</NumeroPolice>
<Nom>LOUKACH</Nom>
<Prenom>EL-MEHDI</Prenom>
<DateNaissance>1998-01-05T00:00:00</DateNaissance>
<Sexe>Homme</Sexe>
<SituationFamille>Celibataire</SituationFamille>
<Cin>L700878</Cin>
<Adresse>Av allal fassi res yasmin wilaya</Adresse>
<Telephone>+212662186047</Telephone>
<Departement>IT</Departement>
<Direction>Casablanca</Direction>
<Secteur>Informatique</Secteur>
<Fonction>Développeur Web</Fonction>
<DateFonction>2019-07-15T00:00:00</DateFonction>
<DateAdhesion>2019-09-10T00:00:00</DateAdhesion>
<NumeroMatricule>1904</NumeroMatricule>
<Salaire>3000</Salaire>
<ConjointId xsi:nil="true" />
<Conjoints>
<ConjointId>0</ConjointId>
<Sexe xsi:nil="true" />
<DateNaissance xsi:nil="true" />
</Conjoints>
<EnfantId xsi:nil="true" />
<Enfants>
<EnfantId>0</EnfantId>
<Sexe xsi:nil="true" />
<DateNaissance xsi:nil="true" />
</Enfants>
<BeneficiaireId xsi:nil="true" />
<BeneficiaireEnCasDeces>
<BeneficiaireId>0</BeneficiaireId>
<Sexe xsi:nil="true" />
<DateNaissance xsi:nil="true" />
<BeneficiaireAyantDroit>false</BeneficiaireAyantDroit>
</BeneficiaireEnCasDeces>
</Adherent>
```

Comment: If you need help on the XSLT side of the code then you need to show us a sample of the XML input you feed to XSLT, we can't guess its structure/elements from some C# code.

Comment: Please publish the XML in a form that people can download and run tests on, not as an image.

Comment: UPDATE : xml source code is added as a code sample for copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path expressions `NumeroAdhesion` and `Nom` aren't selecting anything. They will only select anything if the top level element of the XML matches this name (and there's only one top-level element so it can't match both names). I suspect that these names appear somewhere deep in the document tree and you need a more specific path to select them. Without seeing the source document, that's all we can really tell you.

**UPDATE**

Now you have published your XML source, we can see that the correct paths are `Adherent/NumeroAdhesion` and `Adherent/Nom`.

Comment: Indeed, i have updated the post, there is an image of the XML, so should i search for something else in order to use the data in child element ?

Comment: I assume i should put these paths in the value-of attribute ?

Comment: Thank you sir i really appreciate that, in fact that is totally true, i just started learning about XSLT, i'm following XSLT Documentation on w3schools.com and it got me this far.